# How to get rid of the Shell TabBar Title space using MAUI on iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, maui

Consider the following image:

[image: Screenshot of app on iOS]

I made this using MAUI with the default Shell, like this:

```xml
<Shell
    x:Class="MyApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="using:MyApp.Pages"
    FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    BackgroundColor="Red">
    <TabBar>
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Title="Title" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:MainPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

Because the TabBar is implicitly if you omit it, I just left it.

This Shell is then applied by assigning MainPage on the Application, like so:

```cs
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

I've tried all kinds of different things to hide the title:

- Not assigning a Title to the Tab, but this will just leave one blank space.
- `Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"` and similar options, even by doing it through code before and after component initialization and moving the XAML instruction to the ShellContext XAML instead.
- `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"` seems to do something, but it will also hide the iOS statusbar and still reserve the space.
- I've tried to inspect the element using the XAML debugger, so I can set a IsVisible property or something.
- Assign my page that doesnt have any TabBar at all directly to the `MainPage`, it will still reserve the space then.
- I even went through the MAUI source to scout for something interesting, with no luck.

I'm at a loss by now and simply can't find anything to get it to work. Could someone point me in the right direction to remove the Title and the reserved spacing? All of this seems to work fine on Android and UWP, just not iOS...

Comment: Just tested the `Shell.NavBarIsVisible` on a real iPhone and it appears to be a Simulator issue, sigh.

Comment: Always nice to get down votes without any explanation. Even if that wasn't a Simulator issue, I feel I presented a good question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of sheer desperation, I tested a real iPhone running iOS 16.5, and I have to conclude this is an iOS Simulator related issue, rather than a physical hardware issue. Still, pretty annoying...

The right approach is `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"`, by the way.